# Change a SeekBar position inside its container

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-seekbar

Whenever extending the class, the bar will be drawn in the vertical center of its container. I need to place text above the bar and increasing the height (I am setting an arbitrary height on the view) causes a bunch of blank space beneath the bar. I've been googling for quite some time now but all I find is regarding the thumb mostly, and I need to draw the bar on the bottom of its container.

This is what I'm trying to achieve as a single view (notice how the bar's position in not centered):

[image]

The only "useful" code I could find was this:

```
Window window = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindow();
window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = window.getAttributes();
wmlp.y = getHeight() / 4;
window.setAttributes(wmlp);
```

But it has no effect whatsoever.

My custom class, nothing out of the ordinary:

```
public class RateSeekbar extends AppCompatSeekBar {

    private Paint lettersPaint;
    private Paint numberPaint;

    // constructors and call to init()

    private void init() {
        lettersPaint = new Paint();
        numberPaint = new Paint();
        ... // style the two different paints
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        ... // get a couple of strings from resources and measure them 
        int middleHor = getWidth() / 2;
        canvas.drawText(text1, getPaddingLeft(), 40, lettersPaint);
        canvas.drawText(text2, getWidth() - text2Size - getPaddingRight(), 40, lettersPaint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(getProgress()), middleHor - (text3Size / 2), 50, numberPaint);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share screenshot of what you are trying to achieve and what you currently have, also post your xml

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy there is no XML, I'm working with a single custom view. What I'm trying to achieve is draw the bar on the bottom of its container

Comment: try adding paddingTop in the constructor

Comment: That causes the text I'm drawing in the top to move as well. I need to offset the bar's position only.

Comment: post your code of customview

Comment: There. Current code adds no value...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172190/discussion-between-suhaib-roomy-and-chisko).